# There is no symbol comparison table and English cover in the latex template, how to add？

Tags: macros

[image: This is my current symbol comparison table]
[image: This is what I want to see about symbol comparison table]How should I modify the .tex and .cls files to get the effect I want？
[image: This is what I want to see about English cover]
[image: my.cls]
[image: my.tex]

```
\newcommand{\NMU@denotation@name}{symbol comparison table}
\newenvironment{denotation}[1][2.5cm]{
\chapter{\NMU@denotation@name} % no tocline
\addcontentsline{eoc}{chapter}{List of Denotations}
\noindent\begin{list}{}%
{\vskip-30bp\zihao{-4}
\renewcommand\makelabel[1]{##1\hfil}
\setlength{\labelwidth}{#1} 
\setlength{\labelsep}{0.5cm}
\setlength{\itemindent}{0cm}
\setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth+\labelsep}
\setlength{\rightmargin}{0cm}
\setlength{\parsep}{0cm}
\setlength{\itemsep}{0cm}
\setlength{\listparindent}{0cm}
\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
}}
{\end{list}}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Do not post images of code! Instead add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: It is suggested that you go to the LaTeX template repositorie to ask for issue. If this is the requirement of the school, there should be a template author to uniformly add this function.